# Update or delete existing file and create new file

Tags: java, file, scheduler

I want to create a file name with current time and that will be scheduler which runs every one hour. My problem is I need to replace that file name every scheduled time. Please help me guys how to rename or delete existing file and create new file.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Timer time = new Timer(); // Instantiate Timer Object
    ScheduledTask st = new ScheduledTask(); // Instantiate SheduledTask class
    time.schedule(st, 0, 60 * 60000); // Create Repetitively task for every 1 hour
}

static class ScheduledTask extends TimerTask {
    private Path lastFilePath = null;
    private DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yy_hh_mm");

    // Add your task here
    public void run() {
        try {
            if (lastFilePath != null) {
                Files.delete(lastFilePath);
            }
            LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();
            String fileName = date.format(dtf);
            lastFilePath = Paths.get(fileName);
            Files.createFile(lastFilePath);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```